# use automapper to map single object into a list of objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following line in my mapper:

I am trying to map from one model where I have a single property called Result to a model where I have a List of Results.

I have the following so far:

```
options.CreateMap<Contract.Dto.Result, List<Result>>(MemberList.Source).ConvertUsing<ResultConverter>();


internal class ResultConverter : ITypeConverter<Contract.Dto.Result, List<Result>>
    {
        public List<Result> Convert(Contract.Dto.Result source, List<Result> destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            destination.Add(context.Mapper.Map<Contract.Dto.Result, Result>(source));
            return destination;
        }
    }
```

However, when debugging, the ResultConverter is never hit.
Does anyone have any solution as to how to map from single object to list of objects? There will only ever be one object in this list of objects but other constraints stop me from amending the models.

Comment: If there will always only be one in the list, why is it a list? Can you modify the property to just be Result instead on List<Result>?

Comment: Which version of automapper are you using?

Comment: @lowry0031 no I can't do anything about changing the models. It is what it is.

Comment: @andyb952 automapper version 8.0.0

Comment: Also, have you registered the Converter within your IOC container (if used)? I will take a look at this today as have literally just used a converter and had the same problem but got it working.

Comment: hi @andyb952 thanks for checking this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to get this working in a very small Class Library I created. Bits I noticed that would potentially break your code:

No mention anywhere that you are also mapping  < Contract.Dto.Result, Result > - ensure you have added both these maps

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(options =>
{
    options.CreateMap<Contract.Dto.Result, List<Result>>(MemberList.Source).ConvertUsing<ResultConverter>();
    options.CreateMap<Contract.Dto.Result, Result>(MemberList.Source);
});
```

In your converter, I changed this to use a new list of results rather than destination

```
public List<Result> Convert(Contract.Dto.Result source, List<Result> destination, ResolutionContext context)
{
    var listOfResults = new List<Result>();
    var result = context.Mapper.Map<Contract.Dto.Result, Result>(source);
    listOfResults.Add(result);
    return listOfResults;
}
```

When actually using the map, just ensure you have got the correct syntax

```
var result = new Contract.Dto.Result();
var expected = mapper.Map<List<Result>>(result);
```

Also, if using IOC, make sure you have registered the conveters. Autofac code example below

```
 builder.RegisterType<ResultConverter>().AsSelf();
 builder.Register(context => new MapperConfiguration(options=>
 {
     options.CreateMap<Contract.Dto.Result, List<Result>>(MemberList.Source).ConvertUsing<ResultConverter>();
     options.CreateMap<Contract.Dto.Result, Result>(MemberList.Source);
 })).AsSelf().SingleInstance();


 builder.Register(c =>
 {
     //This resolves a new context that can be used later.
     var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
     var config = context.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>();
     return config.CreateMapper(context.Resolve);
 }).As<IMapper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

As OP mentioned in comment below, also ensure that the correct types are used, in this instance List<> vs IList<>

Give each of these a try on your project, hopefully that will solve your issues. If not let me know and I can take a further look.

Comment: thanks, really appreciate you taking the time. i have the mappings in place that you mention at the top and the call is correct that you mention at the bottom. i have changed my Convert to match what you have suggested but unfortunately i have no change.

Comment: is there any way to do this without using a converting class?

Comment: Are you using any sort of IOC, like autofac or ninject? No I'm pretty sure converters anre the only way to do this, they are definitely the best option anyway

Comment: using Castle Windsor. i'm starting to think that the Converter class isn't even being hit. when debugging, for example, the debugger never enters the code

Comment: Not used castle windor, but I know I had an issue with autofac. I needed to register the converters. Added autofac code above, ensure that it is registered

Comment: Got sorted on this. Simply I had the wrong mapping... where I had this: `internal class ResultConverter : ITypeConverter<Contract.Dto.Result, List<Result>>` i should have had `IList`... List vs IList. Thanks again for all your help. I'm going to add your answer as the accepted answer, because I also need to create a new list in the Convert class : `var listOfResults = new List<Result>();`

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, added correct types to my list of possible issues above!

Answer (score -4):

I didn't use automapper ever. You can try this and please let me know if it works:

```
        //Use this method.
        public void Map(object PreEqual, string PreEqProperty, object PostEqual, string PostEqProperty)
        {
            PreEqual.GetType().GetProperty(PreEqProperty).SetValue(PreEqual, PostEqual.GetType().GetProperty(PostEqProperty).GetValue(PostEqual, null), null);
        }

        //Use Map method somewhere you want, like this:
        //myRefObj is your source object and myRefProp is its property that you want to map to other objects.
        foreach(SomeType item in CollectionOfSomeType)
        {
             Map(item, "myRefProp", myRefObj, "myRefProp");
        }
```

I think it will work with primitive types. Can you try and let me know if it works?

Comment: thanks for the response, but this is specifically an automapper issue.