# Why is my model null after using automapper?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity, automapper

How does automapper work for a list? For simple mapping I am able to do it, but in the case of list, the model is null after mapping. Can somebody help please? What am I doing wrong?

```
class casemodel 
{
  List<documentsmodel> docs {get;set;}
}
class documentsmodel
{
public string filename {get;set;}
}

public class MappingProfile:AutoMapper.Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {           
            CreateMap<List<documentsmodel>, Tbldocument();
        }
    }

public class repository{
public string insert(casemodel model)
        {
        docsModel = _mapper.Map<Tbldocument>(model.docs);              
                _contextObj.Tbldocument.Add(docsModel);
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper: Map single object with list of objects inside to just list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725911/automapper-map-single-object-with-list-of-objects-inside-to-just-list)

Comment: It looks like your mapping isn't correct (e.g. Mapping a List<DocumentsModel> to TbleDocument with no custom mapping isn't going to work because there aren't any properties to match).

Comment: I tried changing mapping but no help.

Comment: @MindingData I tried something like this
CreateMap<List<DocumentAttachementModel>, TblDocumentAttachment>()
                .ForMember(
                dest => dest.FileName,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(s=>s.FileName)
                );
Bu getting error on last line MapFrom(s=>s.FileName) as FileName is not available.

Comment: I think what you are after is a custom type converter. If so, please see one of my previous answers, more than happy to help you if this is the same case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987748/use-automapper-to-map-single-object-into-a-list-of-objects/57037261#57037261